# SSAS - Always show zeros - NOT blanks

Tags: string, null, ssas, cube, zero

I have a cube that I access via Targit (BI Solution).  When I browse / use that cube I want all quantity results to be a zero if null / blank NOT a blank, but no matter what I try I get blanks.  I have changed the Null Processing property for the measure in question as well as attempted to change / remove the format string.  I still get blanks instead of zero's.

Thoughts?

UPDATE:  I figured out that I could create a calculated measure and use iif / isempty funcitons to force zeros.  This works - just wondering if there is a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a formating expression such as FORMAT_STRING = "#.00;(#.00);#.00;-"
This should give the desired results without the perf hit.

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx

Comment: Hi Jason,

Thank you - found this Friday but unfortunately the build of the BI software that I'm using isn't recognizing the formatting.  The latest version does recognize this, so I'm off to upgrade!  This will fit the bill EXACTLY!  Take care.


Bill

Answer (score 0):

There may be two solutions if the source data contains NULL values for measure fields:

1. If you are using a table in the DSV, then replace it either with a view or a Named Query and ISNULL(field_name, 0) the nullable measure fields.
2. Use the calculated measure's code in the MeasureExpression property of the measure within the cube instead of in a separate calculated field.  I've never tried it, but it seems like it would work.

If the problem is not caused by NULL values in the source data, then please elaborate on the problem.

Comment: Hi - Thank you for your response!  Unfortunately, my issue is not due to NULLS in the source data.  The data has been successfully "de-nulled".  My issue happens when I query the cube to show me quantity by month and department and there are certain months / dept combos where that answer is correctly zero - BUT - instead of the cube showing zero it shows a blank.  This causes problems when attempting to create a line chart from the data, as it needs zeros not blanks.  Blanks cause segments of the line to disappear, whereas zeros show correctly at the bottom of the graph as a zero.

Comment: And I'm finding my calculated measure solution is no good, as the performance of the cube is unacceptable AND calculated measures are not included in pre-aggregations so even doing that isn't improving the performance of the cube while still providing the necessary zeros

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Measure Name=IF(SUM(ColumnName)=BLANK(),0,SUM(ColumnName))